# Node app not working when deployed with error Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

my app works locally, but when i deployed it on Heroku, it returns Internal Server Error, below are my settings

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));

const path = require("path");


app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, + "public", 'index.html'));
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");

    //res.send('Testing one two');
});
```

Procfile:

```
"web: npm run dev"
```

when I change the res.sendfile to res.send('hello'), this works

so I use npm run dev to run the app, everything works well unless deployed on heroku, I think I am doing something wrong but I have tried all I can, I wont work. any help please

Comment: what do the logs say? what's the error code? is it 500? what have you written inside the procfile?

Comment: You must have written the wrong command in the Procfile.

Comment: @NishantKumar  i think it is my path, when I swap my res.sendfile to res.send('hello'), this worked

Comment: your server is not rendering the static build folder. Try this path app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  if public is your static build folder

Comment: @NishantKumar the static files are in a folder called live inside the public folder

Comment: why are using a subfolder inside the public? just put all the static files inside the public folder or Anyway just join the path to the parent folder of your static build. In your case, it's gonna be the "public" folder.

Comment: still nor working @NishantKumar

Comment: You have a wild `+` after the comma in `path.join(__dirname, + './public/live', 'index.html')`. That'll throw an error. You'll want to remove that.

Comment: share me a link on code sandbox or GitHub, if it is not private, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: either use this line of code, app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));

OR, this line of code, res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");

If you will use both the latter won't work, it creates middleware issues.

Comment: First comment out this,   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
 and then let me know whether static files are getting served by the server or not, if not then check the path. If it is not working then comment out your path.join(__dirname... code and add enable the res.sendFile(__dirname+... as a response to "/" route. Let me know if it works okay

Comment: @NishantKumar i commented out the res.sendfile and it still works on the localhost but not on heroku

Comment: if you have a GitHub account then upload it and then send me your link and I will fork it and make sure it works for you :)